# Unable to specify maven plugin.xml parameter metadata for collections and complex objects

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to produce a plugin.xml metadata file for an internal maven 3 plugin. The maven-plugin-plugin does an excellent job generating metadata for the top level paramaters, but does not appear to be able to detect and express the configuration requirements of complex objects used as parameters such as required properties.

```
@Mojo(name = "feature")
public class FeatureMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter(required = true)
    private List<Feature> features;

    @Parameter(required = true)
    private Feature feature;
}

public class Feature {

    @Parameter(required = true)
    private String name;
}
```

The current plugin.xml output is:

```
    <parameter>
      <name>feature</name>
      <type>local.example.mojo.Feature</type>
      <required>true</required>
      <editable>true</editable>
      <description></description>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <name>features</name>
      <type>java.util.List</type>
      <required>true</required>
      <editable>true</editable>
      <description></description>
    </parameter>
```

Is there a way around this limitation?

I am not adverse to producing the plugin.xml by hand if this can be expressed in the plugin descriptor and is just a limitation in the generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only specify the toplevel Object. Next, give your feature a getter and setter for `name`. That's all required to make it work like this:

```
<configuration>
  <features>
    <feature>
      <name>NAME</name>
    </feature>
  </features>
</configuration>
```

It is not possible to check the requirement for name inside the instance like this, best is to add a validate-method to your Mojo where you check these extra requirements.

ps. I would remove the `private Feature feature;`. In general choose for single or multipe, never both.

Comment: Fair enough, this is an unfortunate limitation. Perhaps I'll look into that. The nake Feature reference was only to get show that neither method produced the hoped-for results.

Comment: There is often room for improvement, but I don't expect it to be a solved with a parameter annotation, since feature(s) is the parameter, name is just a field of this instance, not a parameter.